# shell function issue - remove the single quote from shell statement

Tags: shell, sh

I am getting a issue running below command:

when I run: cmssh 12np, I meant to invoke the defined function cmssh, eventually I am expecting a shell command line like this:

```
sshpass -p password ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com
```

, see below source:

```
alias 12np='ssh mydomain\\stephencheng@userxyz@host.com'


function cmssh () {
   set -x
   local aliascmd=$1
   cmdstr=$(alias $aliascmd | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d"'" -f2)
   echo $cmdstr
   sshpass -p "$cmpw" $cmdstr
   #debug cmdstr : sshpass -p password 'ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'
}
```

however, the final step always render the result as:

```
sshpass -p password 'ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'
```

I have attempted many ways to try to remove the single quote, but got no idea how it is possible.

See the debug info:

```
~  cmssh 12np
+cmssh:2> local 'aliascmd=12np'
+cmssh:4> cmdstr=+cmssh:4> alias 12np
+cmssh:4> cmdstr=+cmssh:4> cmdstr=+cmssh:4> cut '-d=' -f2
+cmssh:4> cut '-d'\' -f2
+cmssh:4> cmdstr='ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'
+cmssh:7> echo 'ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'
ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com
+cmssh:8> sshpass -p password 'ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

Thanks

Comment: Are there any special characters in your password? If you store your password in `$cmpw` and run `sshpass -p "$cmpw" ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com` at the command line, does it run successfully?

Comment: What shell is executing this? Looks like `bash`, but please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: At this point it is not clear what specific shell the OP uses. This answer makes a general point and then discusses `bash` and `zsh`.</sup>

Your *immediate* problem is unrelated to quoting: The error message suggests that the **executable `sshpass` is not in your `$PATH`**.

Your string (`$cmdstr`) doesn't actually contain single quotes - they are an **artifact of running `bash` or `zsh` with `set -x` in effect**.

However, there are additional issues:

---

The way you parse the alias definition in `cmssh()` turns the `\\` in your alias definition from a (conceptually) *quoted single* `\` into literal string `\\` (two literal `\` chars.)

A simple fix in this case is to add another layer of evaluation by having `xargs` (without arguments) echo the string:

```
cmdstr=$(alias $aliascmd | cut -d"'" -f2 | xargs)
```

Note that I've eliminated the `=`-based `cut` command, which is not needed.

In general, though, parsing alias definitions this way is fragile.

At that point I would expect your code to work in `bash`, though not yet in `zsh` (see below).
Note that simply removing `function`  from the beginning of your function definition would make your code work in `sh` (a POSIX-features-only shell), too.

---

The final problem affects only `zsh`, not `bash`:

`zsh` by default doesn't perform word splitting on `$cmdstr` in the `sshpass -p "$cmpw" $cmdstr` command, so that `'ssh mydomain\userxyz@host.com'` is passed as a SINGLE argument to `sshpass`.

To turn on word splitting when evaluating `$cmdstr` and thus pass its tokens as separate arguments, refer to it as `${=cmdstr}`:

```
sshpass -p "$cmpw" ${=cmdstr}
```

Note that this feature is `zsh`-specific.

Comment: This solution worked. Yes, it's in zsh. And your answer is great. I spent a day on this and was aware what issue is. Thanks very much. Could you help extend a little bit to support both bash and zsh by adding some condition logic there: like function cmssh () {
   local aliascmd=$1
   cmdstr=$(alias $aliascmd | cut -d"'" -f2 | xargs)

   if (it is zsh):
      sshpass -p "$cmpw" ${=cmdstr}
   else:
      sshpass -p "$cmpw" $cmdstr
}  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I figure it out, I export a varible eg, WHICH_SHELL="BASH" for the runtime to detect. It works.

Comment: @stephencheng: Glad to hear it; you can actually rely on variables that `bash` and `zsh` automatically define: `bash` defines `$BASH_VERSION` (among others), and `zsh` defines `$ZSH_VERSION`. For instance, `[[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]]` will only be true in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mydomain="'ssh mydomain\\userxyz@host.com'"

echo ${mydomain/#'/\\\'} \\ assign this variable
```

Other way to do this,using sed

```
echo $mydomain | sed -s "s/^\(\(\"\(.*\)\"\)\|\('\(.*\)'\)\)\$/\\3\\5/g"
```